# BSP Sieve Of Erastothenes C implementation gives Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, sieve-of-eratosthenes, bulk-synchronous-parallel

EDIT EDIT: This is my problem after using the program in the second comment, original post is below.

```
    > ./bspsieve 8 10                           processors to use: 8
upper bound: 10
It took : 0.000076 seconds for proc 0 out of 8.
*** glibc detected *** ./bspsieve: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x000000000060d040 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x75218)[0x7fbacd7c2218]
./bspsieve[0x4015f7]
./bspsieve[0x401728]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6)[0x7fbacd76bbc6]
./bspsieve[0x401119]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-0040b000 r-xp 00000000 00:1a 5278668                            /vsc-mounts/leuven-user/gst/guest043/ParCoSieve/MulticoreBSP-for-C/bspsieve
0060b000-0060c000 r--p 0000b000 00:1a 5278668                            /vsc-mounts/leuven-user/gst/guest043/ParCoSieve/MulticoreBSP-for-C/bspsieve
0060c000-0060d000 rw-p 0000c000 00:1a 5278668                            /vsc-mounts/leuven-user/gst/guest043/ParCoSieve/MulticoreBSP-for-C/bspsieve
0060d000-0062e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fba48000000-7fba48021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fba48021000-7fba4c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7fba4d26e000-7fba4d284000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 7531397                    /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
7fba4d284000-7fba4d483000 ---p 00016000 08:06 7531397                    /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
7fba4d483000-7fba4d484000 r--p 00015000 08:06 7531397                    /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
7fba4d484000-7fba4d485000 rw-p 00016000 08:06 7531397                    /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
7fbacd74d000-7fbacd8a2000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 7531274                    /lib64/libc-2.11.1.so
7fbacd8a2000-7fbacdaa1000 ---p 00155000 08:06 7531274                    /lib64/libc-2.11.1.so
7fbacdaa1000-7fbacdaa5000 r--p 00154000 08:06 7531274                    /lib64/libc-2.11.1.so
7fbacdaa5000-7fbacdaa6000 rw-p 00158000 08:06 7531274                    /lib64/libc-2.11.1.so
7fbacdaa6000-7fbacdaab000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fbacdaab000-7fbacdb00000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 7531290                    /lib64/libm-2.11.1.so
7fbacdb00000-7fbacdcff000 ---p 00055000 08:06 7531290                    /lib64/libm-2.11.1.so
7fbacdcff000-7fbacdd00000 r--p 00054000 08:06 7531290                    /lib64/libm-2.11.1.so
7fbacdd00000-7fbacdd01000 rw-p 00055000 08:06 7531290                    /lib64/libm-2.11.1.so
7fbacdd01000-7fbacdd09000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 7531329                    /lib64/librt-2.11.1.so
7fbacdd09000-7fbacdf08000 ---p 00008000 08:06 7531329                    /lib64/librt-2.11.1.so
7fbacdf08000-7fbacdf09000 r--p 00007000 08:06 7531329                    /lib64/librt-2.11.1.so
7fbacdf09000-7fbacdf0a000 rw-p 00008000 08:06 7531329                    /lib64/librt-2.11.1.so
7fbacdf0a000-7fbacdf21000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 7531435                    /lib64/libpthread-2.11.1.so
7fbacdf21000-7fbace121000 ---p 00017000 08:06 7531435                    /lib64/libpthread-2.11.1.so
7fbace121000-7fbace122000 r--p 00017000 08:06 7531435                    /lib64/libpthread-2.11.1.so
7fbace122000-7fbace123000 rw-p 00018000 08:06 7531435                    /lib64/libpthread-2.11.1.so
7fbace123000-7fbace127000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fbace127000-7fbace146000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 17398545                   /lib64/ld-2.11.1.so
7fbace30b000-7fbace30f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fbace343000-7fbace345000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fbace345000-7fbace346000 r--p 0001e000 08:06 17398545                   /lib64/ld-2.11.1.so
7fbace346000-7fbace347000 rw-p 0001f000 08:06 17398545                   /lib64/ld-2.11.1.so
7fbace347000-7fbace348000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fff10a45000-7fff10a5a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff10ae3000-7fff10ae4000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

=================
Original Post

I am trying to implement a simple parallel version of the Sieve Of Erastothenes in C using the BSP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_synchronous_parallel) library.

I am inexperienced with both C and BSP. So far I have 2 questions:
1) After compiling (as done by the instructions) and trying to run the program with the ./bspsieve 200 I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

2) Any other things I am doing wrong? I'm not looking for a good algorithm, just one that gives the desired results.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <mcbsp.h>


/*
Note: To compile, this file has to be in the same folder as mcbsp.h and you need the 2 following commands:
gcc -Iinclude/ -pthread -c -o bspsieve.o bspsieve.c
gcc -o bspsieve bspsieve.o lib/libmcbsp1.1.0.a -lpthread -lrt

*/

  int procs;
  float upperbound;
  int *primes;

//SPMD function
void bspSieve(){
    bsp_begin(procs);

    float p = bsp_nprocs(); // p = number of procs obtained 
    int s = bsp_pid();  // s = proc number

    float blocksize;    // block size to be used, note last proc has a different size!
    if( s != p){
        blocksize = ceil(upperbound/p); 
    } else {
        blocksize = upperbound - (p-1)*ceil(upperbound/p);
    }

    // Initialize start time and end time, set start time to now.   
    double start_time,end_time;
    start_time = bsp_time();

    // Create vector that has block of candidates
    int *blockvector;
    blockvector = (int *)malloc(blocksize*sizeof(int));
    int q;
    for(q = 0; q<blocksize; q++){
    //List contains the integers from s*blocksize till blocksize + s*blocksize
      blockvector[q] = q + s*blocksize;
    } 

    //We neglect the first 2 'primes' in processor 0.
     if(s == 0){
        blockvector[0] = 0;
        blockvector[1] = 0;
     }

    // We are using the block distribution. We assume that n is large enough  to
    // assure that n/p is larger than sqrt(n). This means that we will always find the
    // sieving prime in the first block, and so have to broadcast from the first 
    // processor to the others.
     long sieving_prime;
     int i;
     bsp_push_reg( &sieving_prime,sizeof(long) );
     for(i = 2; i * i < upperbound; i++) {
       //Part 1: if first processor, get the newest sieving prime, broadcast. Search for newest prime starting from i.
        if(s == 0){
       int findPrimeNb;
       for(findPrimeNb = i; findPrimeNb <= blocksize; findPrimeNb++) {
          if( blockvector[findPrimeNb] != 0) {
                 sieving_prime  = blockvector[findPrimeNb];
                 //broadcast
         int procNb;
         for(procNb = 0; procNb < p; ++procNb){
                     bsp_put(procNb, &sieving_prime,&sieving_prime,0,sizeof(long));
        }
             break;
          }
           }
    }
        bsp_sync();

    //Part 2: Sieve using the sieving prime
    int sievingNb;
    for(sievingNb = 0; sievingNb < blocksize; sievingNb++){
       //check if element is multiple of sieving prime, if so, pcross out (put to zero)
       if( blockvector[sievingNb] % sieving_prime == 0){
          blockvector[sievingNb] = 0;
           }
    }

     }

     //part 3: get local primes to central area
     int transferNb;
     long transferPrime;
     for(transferNb = 0; transferNb < blocksize; transferNb++){
        transferPrime = blockvector[transferNb];
        primes[transferPrime] = transferPrime;
     }

     // take the end time.
     end_time = bsp_time();

   //Print amount of taken time, only processor 0 has to do this.
   if( s == 0 ){
      printf("It took : %.6lf seconds for proc %d out of %d. \n", end_time-start_time, bsp_pid(), bsp_nprocs());
      fflush(stdout);
   }

   bsp_end();
}



int main(int argc, char **argv){

    primes = (int *)malloc(upperbound*sizeof(int));

    if(argc != 2) {
    printf( "processors to use: %s ", argv[ 0 ] );
    printf( "upper bound: %s ", argv[ 1 ] );
    }
    //retrieve parameters
    procs = atoi( argv[ 1 ] );
    upperbound = atoi( argv[ 2 ] );

    // init and call parallel part
    bsp_init(bspSieve, argc, argv); 
    bspSieve();


   //Print all non zeros of candidates, these are the primes.
   // Primes only go to p*p <= n
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i*i <= upperbound; i++) {
        if(primes[i] > 0) {
        printf("%d, ",primes[i]);
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I've done the following to fix the mistake noticed by mathematician1975, however I still get the Segmentation Faults.

```
    int main(int argc, char **argv){

    if(argc != 2) {
    printf( "processors to use: %s ", argv[ 0 ] );
    printf( "upper bound: %s ", argv[ 1 ] );
    }
    //retrieve parameters
    procs = atoi( argv[ 1 ] );
    upperbound = atoi( argv[ 2 ] );

    primes = (int *)malloc(upperbound*sizeof(int));
    // init and call parallel part
    bsp_init(bspSieve, argc, argv); 
    bspSieve();

   //Print all non zeros of candidates, these are the primes.
   // Primes only go to p*p <= n
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i*i <= upperbound; i++) {
        if(primes[i] > 0) {
        printf("%d, ",primes[i]);
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seconded, @James!   Fire up your favorite debugger and it will halt and show you the line of code where you went wrong.  Often this is the very spot where the bug was introduced.  Occasionally, it's only a victim of some earlier memory corruption.

Comment: I'll try, but again, I'm completely unused to C. First time I heard of gdb even... I'm also working on this algorithm from a remote computer so hopefully they have it.

The point of the assignment also isn't learning to work with C, otherwise I would go more in depth for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem in your loop in main

```
primes = (int *)malloc(upperbound*sizeof(int)); <-- upperbound determines size of                            
                                                    memory allocated


upperbound = atoi( argv[ 2 ] );  <-- changing array limit

// init and call parallel part
bsp_init(bspSieve, argc, argv); 
bspSieve();



int i;
for(i = 0; i*i <= upperbound; i++) {   <-- Array limit not necessarily true
```

because you change the array size limit but use it in your loop to determine array bounds. This depending on what `upperbound` changes to you may allow access to memory you have not allocated and that could give you a segfault.

Comment: Thank you, I included my fix above. I still get faults however, probably something else.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a corrected version of your code. The debugging tool I used was valgrind. Install it, compile bspsieve with `-g`, and use `valgrind 8 30 ./bspsieve` and you will be told info about any memory errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <mcbsp.h>

/*
Compile using
gcc -Wall -g -o bspsieve bspsieve.c lib/libmcbsp1.1.0.a -pthread -lrt -lm -Iinclude
*/

int procs;
float upperbound;
int *primes;

//////////////// //////////////// BSPSIEVE

//SPMD function
void
bspSieve ()
{
    bsp_begin (procs);

    float p = bsp_nprocs ();    // p = number of procs obtained 
    int s = bsp_pid (); // s = proc number

    float blocksize;    // block size to be used, note last proc has a different size!
    if (s != p-1) {
        blocksize = ceil (upperbound / p);
    }
    else {
        blocksize = upperbound - (p - 1) * ceil (upperbound / p);
    }

    // Initialize start time and end time, set start time to now.   
    double start_time, end_time;
    start_time = bsp_time ();

    // Create vector that has block of candidates
    int *blockvector;
    blockvector = (int *) malloc (blocksize * sizeof (int));
    int q;
    for (q = 0; q < blocksize; q++) {
        //List contains the integers from s*blocksize till blocksize + s*blocksize
        blockvector[q] = q + s * blocksize;
    }

    //We neglect the first 2 'primes' in processor 0.
    if (s == 0) {
        blockvector[0] = 0;
        blockvector[1] = 0;
    }

    // We are using the block distribution. We assume that n is large enough  to
    // assure that n/p is larger than sqrt(n). This means that we will always find the
    // sieving prime in the first block, and so have to broadcast from the first 
    // processor to the others.
    long sieving_prime;
    int i;
    bsp_push_reg (&sieving_prime, sizeof (long));
    bsp_sync ();
    for (i = 2; i * i < upperbound; i++) {
        //Part 1: if first processor, get the newest sieving prime, broadcast. Search for newest prime starting from i.
        if (s == 0) {
            int findPrimeNb;
            for (findPrimeNb = i; findPrimeNb <= blocksize; findPrimeNb++) {
                if (blockvector[findPrimeNb] != 0) {
                    sieving_prime = blockvector[findPrimeNb];
                    //broadcast
                    int procNb;
                    for (procNb = 0; procNb < p; ++procNb) {
                        bsp_put (procNb, &sieving_prime, &sieving_prime, 0,
                               sizeof (long));
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        bsp_sync ();

        //Part 2: Sieve using the sieving prime
        int sievingNb;
        for (sievingNb = 0; sievingNb < blocksize; sievingNb++) {
            //check if element is multiple of sieving prime, if so, pcross out (put to zero)
                    if (blockvector[sievingNb] != sieving_prime)
            if (blockvector[sievingNb] % sieving_prime == 0) {
                blockvector[sievingNb] = 0;
            }
        }

    }

    //part 3: get local primes to central area
    int transferNb;
    long transferPrime;
    for (transferNb = 0; transferNb < blocksize; transferNb++) {
        transferPrime = blockvector[transferNb];
        primes[transferPrime] = transferPrime;
    }

    // take the end time.
    end_time = bsp_time ();

    //Print amount of taken time, only processor 0 has to do this.
    if (s == 0) {
        printf ("It took : %.6lf seconds for proc %d out of %d. \n",
            end_time - start_time, bsp_pid (), bsp_nprocs ());
        fflush (stdout);
    }

    bsp_end ();
}

//////////////// //////////////// //////////////// //////////////// MAIN

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{

    if (argc != 3) {
            printf("Usage: %s <processor count> <upper bound>\n", argv[0]);
            exit(1);
    }

    printf ("processors to use: %s \n", argv[1]);
    printf ("upper bound: %s \n", argv[2]);     //retrieve parameters

    procs = atoi (argv[1]);
    upperbound = atoi (argv[2]);

    primes = (int *) malloc (upperbound * sizeof (int));
    // init and call parallel part
    bsp_init (bspSieve, argc, argv);
    bspSieve ();

    //Print all non zeros of candidates, these are the primes.
    // DO Primes only go to p*p <= n? The rest of the numbers seem to be prime
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < upperbound; i++) {
        if (primes[i] > 0) {
            printf ("%d, ", primes[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!

When I try your program however, I run into a problem (both when compiling it 'my' way and 'your' way), it prints this:  See original post.